# Listing files in Directory without the path

Tags: php, directory, directory-listing

Im using the following to list the files in a directory in a intranet site I am making. The problem is that is is also listing the path to the file too, does anyone know what im doing wrong ?.
thanks :-)

```
    <?php 
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./customer-files/28734f6d045f8a5a93.18936710')) as $filename) 
    { 
    echo '<p>';
          echo "$filename\n";
    echo '</p>'; 
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the path you're passing, just use either:

```
str_replace($path,'',$filename);
```

or

```
substr($filename,strlen($path));
```

If you don't want ANY PATH in there, you can just get the filename with `$filename->getFilename();`
however, that will lead to confusion, as subdirectories won't be visible.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the `$filename->getFilename()` route as favoring the string functions seems like a micro-optimization but +1 nevertheless.

Comment: My concern is listed for getFilenme, as you can't see subdirectory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just use `basename()`

```
echo basename($filename) . "\n";
```